# ¿Cómo puedo poner los metadatos para visualizar Social Cards cuando se comparte enlaces?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meta-tags

¡Hola buenas! Estoy algo desesperado porque he de insertar los meta tags con los Open Graph y twitter:card.

El tema es que los tengo que meter mediante js por cómo está estructurado el proyecto.

Hay un componente de React llamado meta que es un componente que coge valores y te genera las etiquetas.

Tengo hecha una función que lo que hace es meter dichas etiquetas. Os dejo trozo de código.

```
const ogType = document.createElement('meta');
    ogType.setAttribute('property', 'og:type');
    ogType.setAttribute('content', 'article');
```

Repito el mismo código por cada meta tag que necesito y luego los inserto de esta manera.

```
document.head.prepend(ogType); //También lo hice con .append
...
```

Al final del todo pues el buen hook de UseEffect para que se inserte bien:

```
React.useEffect(function () {
    setSomething();
    setAnotherSomething();
    setMetaTags(); //-> Esa es mi función que crea e inserta los tags
  }, []);
```

Al desplegar la página veo que dentro del campo head se llena correctamente con los meta tags.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Blablabla blablabal blablabla">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://miWeb.com/imagen.jpg?format=WEBP&amp;width=720&amp;height=720&amp;scale=true&amp;is_admin=true">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://miWeb.com/este_articulo">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="blablabla blablabla">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://miWeb.com/imagen.jpg?format=WEBP&amp;width=720&amp;height=720&amp;scale=true&amp;is_admin=true">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@miWeb">
```

Pues cuando lo pasamos al servidor de desarollo para probar mediante las Herramientas de depuracion de Twitter, Facebook y linkedIn:

Twitter: [Card Validator Twitter](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator)

Facebook: [Depurador de contenido compartido](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)

linkedIn: [Post Inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/)

Me encuentro que en twitter me lanza esto:

```
INFO:  Page fetched successfully
INFO:  5 metatags were found // ¿5? Como podéis haber visto arriba son bastantes más (mas otros que no he puesto aquí)
ERROR: No card found (Card error)
```

Facebook me lanza esto, Pero se previsualiza todo menos la imagen:

```
Propiedad inferida
La propiedad "og:image" debe proporcionarse de forma explícita, incluso si puede deducirse su valor a partir de otras etiquetas.
```

LinkedIn me lanza esto, pero también se previsualiza todo menos la imagen:

```
Add an og:image tag to the page to have control over the content's image on LinkedIn.
```

Como podéis ver, aparece claramente el tag de og:image y por alguna razón no lo está leyendo. Al igual que el twitter:card. Directamente dice que no existe cuando podéis ver que sí está.

¿Algún samaritano que pueda arrojarme algo de luz para solucionar esto? ¿Me falta algún meta tag por implementar y lo he obviado? ¿Qué requisitos exactos necesito para que se previsualice todo correctamente?

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Tuve un problema igual y probando varias cosas encontré que agregándole la property

```
<meta property="og:image:secure_url"  content="https://pagina.com/imagen.jpg" />
```

debajo de `og:image` (ambas con la misma url) me devolvía la imagen.
Además, si la imagen no es jpg, al parecer no la toma como válida.